# Getting an error: list assignment index out of range

Tags: python, python-2.7, list

I am getting an error list assignment index out of range in the following code:

```
n=input("How many numbers?\n")
print "Enter ",n," numbers..."
a=[]
for i in range(0,n):
    a[i]=input()

elem=input("Enter the element to be searched: ")

for i in range(0,n):
    if a[i]==elem:
        flag=1
        break

if flag==1:
    print "Item is present in the list"
else:
    print "Item is not present in the list"
```

Comment: Use `a.append()`, not `a[i] = `.

Comment: Please post the stack trace. Python was nice enough to give you details about the error... pay that forward!

Answer (score 1):

Adding some type safety with *int*, using list method *append* and operator *in*:

```
n = input("How many numbers?\n")
n = int(n)
print "Enter ", n, " numbers..."
a = []
for i in range(n):
    x = input()
    a.append(x)

elem = input("Enter the element to be searched: ")

if elem in a:
    print "Item is present in the list"
else:
    print "Item is not present in the list"
```

Answer (score 0):

You're setting a list index without it declaring. See:

```
a=[]
```

Then you want to access some index?And you're reading a string with input,convert it before using. Things will look like:

```
n = int(n)
a= []*n
```

Answer (score 0):

Use it like this,

```
n=input("How many numbers?\n")
print "Enter ",n," numbers..."
# assigning with n times zero values which will get overwritten when you input values.
a=[0]*n
for i in range(0,n):
    a[i]=input()

elem=input("Enter the element to be searched: ")

for i in range(0,n):
    if a[i]==elem:
        flag=1
        break

if flag==1:
    print "Item is present in the list"
else:
    print "Item is not present in the list"
```